# What is wrong with my code, It says invalid syntax.(In a quiz practice)

Tags: python-3.x

```
answer = True
print()
while answer:
    print("Question 9:")
    print()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("What is 'Amino acids'? ")
    print("a. - Produced when proteins are digested."
    import random
    lines16 = open('00newfile.txt').read().splitlines()
    myline16 =random.choice(lines16)
    print("b.", myline16)
    lines17 = open('00newfile.txt').read().splitlines()
    myline17 =random.choice(lines17)
    print("c.", myline17)
    print()
    answer = input("Make your choice: ")
    if answer == "b" or answer == "c":
        print("That is incorrect!")
    elif answer == "a":
        print("That is absolutely correct!")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        answer = False
    else:
        print("Invalid!")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')
```

It prints out:

```
Invalid syntax, at import random
```

I don't know why.Can anyone help, thanks.

Comment: Because your syntax is invalid. Count your parentheses.

Comment: A good place to start with debugging syntax errors is usually the line above where you're told the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Check Line 8 just above the line you're told the error is.

```
print("a. - Produced when proteins are digested.")
                                                 ^ that's what you are missing.
```